# FreeCiv will not build because of an error against curl

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, curl, make, c

I am currently trying to build FreeCiv. But I am unable to do so. The error says that there are many commands used that are undefined references when using Curl commands. I sadly could not get a copy of the error as it is too long. I am using `libcurl-dev` as my main libcurl package. I am unable to find the error in the Makefile as well as the code itself. Am i able to have a little help?

As of my edit, `libcurl-dev` is not working because `<curl/curl.h>` is unable to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

If you run into this error, try downloading the source again and rebuild it.

My problem was that i accidentally deleted the checks for libcurl. And it wasn't included at all.

Don't be me...